# Suppliers for revision-controlled hardware, long-life motherboards?

Tags: hardware

Has anyone had good experience with suppliers of industrial computers, specifically 'long-life, revision-controlled' motherboards?  I'm found a couple of likely candidates including ITOX, BCM, and DuroPC but haven't been able to find much in the way of independent review.

I'm currently using off the shelf motherboards for an industrial data-acquisition system and am trying to eliminate the problem of rapid turnover/obsolescence of motherboards.

Answer (score 1):

I use PFU systems and Advantech.  The key is that you need to work with a vendor who is plugged into Intel's "Embedded Roadmap."  The parts (cpu, chipset, etc) on that roadmap are specifically supported for 7 years or more from their introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Beckhoff's Industrial pcs.

http://www.beckhoff.com/

I have had good experiences with them.